# Where is the compiled dll for a Website project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

One query regarding a Web-Site project in Visual Studio -

I did following steps -

- Created a WebSite using VS 2010
- Added a custom class in App_Code folder and consumed it in default.aspx
- Run the application and I can see the result
- Any changes made in server code are reflected on the browser without doing any recompile (website feature)

So, when dynamic recompilation takes place for a web-site, somewhere .net run-time will be storing the compiled dll, isn't it?

Can anyone please guide where I can find the dll being generated during dynamic build are stored? (I just want to know this out of curiosity :-))

Thank you!

P.S. I also did a 'Publish Website' and I can see a bunch of compiled dlls in the publish folder. So, my Question is only regarding dynamic build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the name & location of *Code Gen Directory* via property of `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` programatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The directory for temp files is C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\<WebSiteName> (in Windows7)

Answer (score 6):

The dynamic created files for your web site are stored on

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

You can change this directory on the web.config. The asp.net check if any file change on your site and if can find any changes is start the recompile. Also many parameters of the recompile can change on web.config.

How to change this directory

```
<compilation  tempDirectory="" ...>
```

and this is the rest of the compile options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing 'tempDirectory' option