# If seems I have duplicate dll, but I have tried to elimate or then the other... they both are required

Tags: sitecore, yaf

Hi I am trying to load/install a software product called "YAF" YetAnotherForum"... it runs great as a standalone, but now I am trying to integrate it in my Sitecore CMS system so that I may utilize the single sign-on features and create an IFrame. in any case, I am making some progress but this is my current error that I cannot seem to get past, any help will be appreciated.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'YAF.Forum' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\App_Code.70udshq8.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\assembly\dl3\698b7e4b\be26b750_b845ce01\YAF.DLL'

```
Line 18:     <img src="~/images/YAFLogo.jpg" runat="server" alt="YetAnotherForum" id="imgBanner" /><br/>
Line 19:     <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Line 20:         <YAF:Forum runat="server" ID="forum"></YAF:Forum>   
Line 21:     </form>
Line 22: </body>
```

Comment: Which .NET framework version? Maybe more than one GAC - see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660366/2065121

Comment: Hi Roger, I am sorry I didn't provide that... .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of Sitecore modules available on marketplace, which offer various types of integration with YAF:

- [YAF Integration](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/YAF_integration.aspx)
- [YAF Single sign-on](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/YAF_Single_Sign-On.aspx)
- [Sitecore YAF](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_YAF.aspx)

I would recommend you review these options, choose the one which fits your requirements, and follow the guideline to set it up and configure.

Comment: Thank you Yan! I have downloaded all and I am moving forward!! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe YAF uses the "Web Site Project" project type which uses dynamic compilation rather than the "Web Application" project type, which you would generally use with Sitecore and which are pre-compiled. See [MSDN definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

The dynamic compilation folder is the path mentioned in the error. [See this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018403/where-is-the-compiled-dll-for-a-website-project) about how it's used.

The GAC is something else, and isn't being cited in the error. I would expect that clearing the temporary ASP.net files folder and restarting the application should fix it. Here's a related answer about [clearing this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081307/question-on-temporary-asp-net-files).

Answer (score 0):

Clear the global assembly cache, that might help.

Run the Gacuitl tool with the command `gacutil /u YAF.Forum.dll`

Also remove all files from the folder `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`. Stop your IIS before clearing so there won't be any locked files.

Then restart IIS and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, I will try and let you know if it works!

Comment: Hi Martin, I have been inside of the c:/windows/assemby table ... I am not finding anything in their to uninstall: based on this message what am I looking for:                                                                CS0433: The type 'YAF.Forum' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\assembly\dl3\698b7e4b\be26b750_b845ce01\YAF.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\App_Code.m3lcmhyi.dll'

Comment: This is resolved ... it seems I had a folder inside of the application... duplicating efforts Thank you for all your help!